# how can connect from client to sql server 2008 via proxy

Tags: sql-server-2008, proxy, windows-firewall

1. I have SQL Server 2008 in dedicated server and all port of SQL Server is blocked with firewall.
2. I have VPS with CCProxy on it.
3. I opened all ports in dedicated server for my VPS server IP.
4. I set proxy in internet option (Windows 7) and proxy is work in internet surfing, but I can't connect to SQL from client.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the path is:

client --> CCProxy --> SQL Server

Right?

First step is probably to use telnet to walk the walk:

On proxy box:

telnet sql-server-host 1433

(Or whatever your sql server port is, if not sure, check errorlog on sql server to see what port it is listening on)

If that telnet connects, the next step is to telnet from client to ccproxy, which should cause connection to go through ccproxy to sql server.

This should help surface where the issue is.